# How to add multiple facebook callback urls

Tags: facebook

I have a product (eg: somedomain.com) where people can create their own subdomains (eg http://xyz.somedomain.com) or even map their domains to it (eg: example.com)

Now, I want to offer a feature so that my customers can enable "Login with facebook" feature into their subdomain.

Since facebook requires us to add a list of URLs under "Client OAuth Settings" > "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"

[Click for Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/26tg672ytiorp9f/Screenshot%202015-09-03%2021.44.19.png?dl=0)

What can I do so that it allows my product's subdomain (eg http://xyz.somedomain.com) or customer domains (eg: example.com)

Thanks

Comment: If you add you main domain under "Basic Settings" -> "App Domains" and add you main domain there this should work. This is also good for security.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question:

If you want your FB app to support wildcard subdomains (for eg http://*.yourdomain.com) then you should leave the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field empty in your app. But make sure your "App Domain" field is set to "yourdomain.com" and your "Site URL" field is to "http://yourdomain.com"

I had a hard time figuring this thing out and finally succeeded after a week of research.  Hope this will be helpful for people struggling with the same problem.

*Bonus tip:*
In case if your FB app doesn't allow to leave the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field empty, try to create a new app. When you create a new fb app, it will set the field empty by default. So leave it as is and you should be fine.

Comment: Leaving that field blank results in an error when trying to save if you already have the information empty, and when you have an established app simply deleting your app is not a viable option.

Comment: @Sean, I do agree with you but creating a new app was the only solution i found.

Comment: @Sean, Have you figured how to allow subdomain login without filling this field with all the possibilities?

Comment: Unfortunately no I have not.  I submitted a question to facebook about it, never heard back.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple callback URLs on the "Settings" -> "Advanced" screen. Scroll down to OAuth configuration, add the URLs and then save.

Answer (score 0):

just add callback url you want to be redirected in 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs' input and define the one you want  to be redirected in your fbconfig page, in the '`FacebookRedirectLoginHelper()`' class.

Note: multiple url can be added in 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs' input. You just need to choose the one you want to be used in the '`FacebookRedirectLoginHelper()`' class.

Answer (score -3):

Hi @Phantom007 how can add support for custom domains as well like example.com, my.com and many more with sub domain of somedomain.com

Comment: Please use the comment section

Comment: @abhishek-mittal I dont know pandey ji ;)