# Does FaceBook allow wildcards in 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs'

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am trying to create a website that can run on a few different subdomains that has FaceBook integration.  I would ideally like domain1.mysite.com and domain2.mysite.com etc etc to work with 1 Facebook app, and not have to set each one individually in the app's 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs'.

This: [How to add multiple facebook callback urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551192/how-to-add-multiple-facebook-callback-urls/32645212#32645212)  is the only thing I have found on the topic.  While it does work, I am unsure if that is properly secure or if it just happens to work and will get fixed up at a later date.  Anyone have some insight on this?

Comment: There is no issue on using subdomains for FB login so I don't think you should worried about this feature to be blocked in the future.